# How can I make a front end web page to login to a page using password and username using python bottle

Tags: python

Using python bottle create a login web page

Answer (score 1):

Bottle by itself does not provide any facility for managing authentication. You will have have to roll your own, or use a WSGI middleware like [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/1.0/) to handle authentication.